# Use generics in Angular route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, typescript-generics, angular-resolver

I want to know if it's possible to use (Typescript) generics in a Angular [Route](https://angular.io/api/router/Route), in any way possible.

Best way would be if I could use generics with the component itself:

```
// the route:
{
  path: 'user-a',
  component: UserComponent<UserA> // other routes will use UserB and UserC
}

// the component:
@Component({...})
export class UserComponent<T> { ... }
```

This obviously gives an error, but it gives a good idea of what I want to accomplish.

Another method would be to use generics with the [Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve):

```
// the route:
{
    path: '/user-b',
    component: UserComponent, 
    resolve: { user: UserResolver<UserB> }
}

// the resolver:
export class UserResolver<T> implements Resolve<boolean> {}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60871476/906308) used this method, but for me it gives an error at `UserResolver<UserB>`: *"Value of type 'typeof UserResolver' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?"*

Comment: Just curious.. but why would you want this..? What does this give you on the component side?

Comment: @MikeOne Good question. Actually I'm sending the components to a private library to make dynamic components. For simplicity I just explained the problem in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how I could of missed this, but the value of a [data](https://angular.io/api/router/Data) property on a angular Route can be of `any` type. Which means you can do this:

```
// the route in app-routing.module.ts
{
  path: 'user-a',
  component: UserComponent,
  data: {
    componentType: UserA
  }
}

// UserComponent:
@Component({...})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const componentType: any = this.route.snapshot.data['componentType'];
  }

}
```

Somehow I always assumed the value of a data property could only be a string, but the docs clear state `any`.